# showing tips or announcements when sites and store info in cookies

Tags: cookies

how to use cookies to store whether a particular announcement is show to user.

for example when we open stackoverflow for first time, it will show an announcement to read FAQ, if we close the announcement, the next time we open the site the announcement won't shown. so this information is stored in cooki. am i correct?

any advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Rifky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You store a cookie, say named "announcement_seen".

Before displaying the announcement, you check the cookie value (on backend or front end, doesn't matter), and if it's 1, you don't display it.

When you DO display the announcement, you run a JavaScript on the browser to set the cookie value to 1.